# Angular 2 error TS2339: Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'BookComponent'

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am learning Angular 2 and am currently blocked by the following error. The variable posts is declared in post.component.ts.

```
Error: src/app/book.component.html:231:33 - error TS2339: Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'BookComponent'.

231         <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
                                    ~~~~~

  src/app/book.component.ts:9:18
    9     templateUrl: 'book.component.html',
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component BookComponent.
```

Here are the relevant components:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BookComponent } from './book.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomPipe } from './custom.pipe';
import { ForEmailDirective } from './for-email.directive';
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BookComponent,
    CustomPipe,
    ForEmailDirective,
    PostComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [BookComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

post.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent {

  posts;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe(response=>{
        //console.log(response);
        this.posts=response;
      })
  }
}
```

book.component.ts - not sure if the issue is here or not. I have attempted to import post.component.ts here but it is not used and appears to be done at a higher level

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ImageValidator } from './image.validator';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-book',
    templateUrl: 'book.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['book.component.css'],
})

// Reactive Form
export class BookComponent {
    bookForm=new FormGroup({
        name:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
        writer:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        price:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        image:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, ImageValidator.isValidExtension])
    })

    get name(){
        return this.bookForm.get('name');
    }

    get image(){
        return this.bookForm.get('image');
    }

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.bookForm.value);
    }

    updateBook(){
        this.bookForm.patchValue({
            name:'Childhood',
            price:'5'
        })
    }
}
```

book.component.html

```
<post>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
            {{post.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</post>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `posts` is being used in `book.component.html` So It is expected to be declared in `book.component.ts`. Since it is not present it is throwing an error. You should be able to fix this if you can move that block of code within the BookComponent as follows:

```
export class BookComponent {

  posts;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe(response=>{
        //console.log(response);
        this.posts=response;
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: the Udemy class instructor had that in the PostComponent instead of the BookComponent. I have asked the question there as well since all of his code was in that component. I don't understand how his code is working. I thought it had to do with the include in app.module.ts

Comment: @LeeZ Maybe he had the `ngFor` in the `post.component.html`. Can't really say you can point me to his code. But whenever you access variables from markup they are expected to be declared in the associated ts file.

Comment: The instructor had switched components without any indication. by taking part of the snippet in one component and putting it in the other. This is the correct answer